# prevent needless text from showing using tableGrob and gridarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have this PDF rmarkdowndocument. It dynamically creates 3 pages. Each page has a table and 2 charts. BUT below the table you will see this text related to the table. How do I not show that text?

Thank you.

here is the text below the table:

```
FALSE TableGrob (1 x 1) "arrange": 1 grobs
20
FALSE z cells name grob
FALSE 1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[colhead-fg]
FALSE
FALSE ewpage
21
```

here is the code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE}

library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 1:3){

  data = rnorm(1000)
  library(gridExtra)
 q =  rbind(
        round(quantile(data),1),
        round(quantile(data),1),
        round(quantile(data),1)
        )

    t = tableGrob(q)
   t$widths <- unit(rep(1 / ncol(t), ncol(t)), "npc")
   t$heights <- unit(rep(1 / nrow(t), nrow(t)), "npc") # new

   dat= data.frame(x= c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3))
   p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  geom_point() + geom_line()

   print(grid.arrange(t,p,p, nrow = 1))

   cat("\newpage")

}

```
````

Comment: Removing `print()` prevents the TableGrob, etc. output. Removing `cat("\newpage")` prevents the "ewpage" output.

Comment: @bdemarest how then do you make it go to a new page in the loop

Comment: I am trying to put a pagebreak in the loop so the 3 plots print on separate pages

Comment: On my machine, your code knits to pdf without errors, after removing `print()` and removing `cat("\newpage")`. The 3 plots are each put on a separate page. I guess that each time `grid.arrange()` is called, a new page is created.

Comment: That is not happening on my machine. No new pages are created

Comment: You might try adding `grid.newpage()` just above `grid.arrange(...)`. I can't really test it, but it produces the same results for me.

Comment: grid.newpage() does not work for me

Comment: Sorry, I can't test anything else because I can't reproduce the issue. I should add that I am knitting this in rstudio using the "knit to pdf" menu option. Also: R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03), Running under: OS X 10.11.6, rmarkdown_1.3,  knitr_1.14